# How to get attribute value from XML with Java Script?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I'm using an application which has XML and Java Script plugin inside. I need to get value of specified attribute. I'm triying to get TEST element's id value with the following command but wrong value is coming.

```
System.log(document.getDocumentElement("TEST").getAttributes().getNamedItem('id').value);

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Task id="123456">   
    <TEST href="https://portal/api/product/5fb26d98-3590-4b7a-9af6-264468b33a83" id="5fb26d98-3590-4b7a-9af6-264468b33a83" name="TEST" type="application/xml"/>
    <TEST2 href="https://portal/api/product/1fb26d98-3590-4b7a-9af6-264468b33a80" id="1fb26d98-3590-4b7a-9af6-264468b33a80" name="TEST2" type="application/xml"/>
</Task>
```

When I try to this command, "123456" value is coming. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Below statement can give you a desire output:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TEST")[0].getAttribute("id"); 
console.log(x);
```

Comment: I am getting this error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getAttribute" of null".

Comment: it works with this ; document.getElementsByTagName("TEST").item(0).getAttribute("id"); Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

`getDocumentElement` doesn't accept any arguments (it isn't `querySelector` or `getElementsbyTagName`) so the string `"TEST"` is ignored.

It gets the document element, also known as the root element, which is `Task` in this case.